# ApplicationListener cannot be parameterized with arguments?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

So I was setting up a custom ApplicationEvent and ApplicationListener for my Spring batch program. I followed the instructions [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#context-functionality-events) at section 3.13.2

Here is the ApplicationEvent I created

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;

public class DataReaderEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

  private final String progress;
  private final String text;

  public DataReaderEvent(Object source, String progress, String text) {
      super(source);
      this.progress = progress;
      this.text = text;
  }

  public String getProgress() {
      return progress;
  }

  public String getText() {
      return text;
  }

}
```

And my ApplicationListener

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;

public class DataReaderNotifier implements ApplicationListener<DataReaderEvent> {

  private String progress;
  private String text;


  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(DataReaderEvent event) {
      this.progress = event.getProgress();
      this.text = event.getText();
  }

  public String getProgress() {
      return progress;
  }

  public String getText() {
      return text;
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the ApplicationListener complains about me trying to do
ApplicationListener < DataReaderEvent >

it says,
    "The type ApplicationListener is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments      DataEventReader"

I don't understand why this would be the case because I think I followed the example pretty closely. If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you have the right (3.0.x+) version of Spring included in your project? I think in 2.5.x ApplicationListener was not generic, so if you're accidentally using that older version then that would cause the problem you're having.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html